# Google Spreadsheets replace function, strange behavior

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheets with some cells containing value between:

- 0,61 and 0,99
- 0,71 and 0,79
- 0,81 and 0,89
- 0,91 and 0,99

These cells are not set as number, they auto-identify contained type. If i check it with ISNUMBER, returns TRUE.

If I find and replace comma with dot separator, it changes the value contained in the cell.
For example "0,75" changes to "1.15". If I click on the cell, it displays "1.15.00".

But if I have values like "1,30", they changes as expected to "1.30", but surprisingly clicking on the cells, it shows "1.30.00".

If I have a cell containing "0,6", "0,7", "0,8", "0,9" set on auto-identify, they change respectively to "0.6", "0.7", "0.8", "0.9".

If I have a cell containing "0,60", "0,70", "0,80", "0,90" set on number, they change respectively to "1.00", "1.10", "1.20", "1.30". If I click on the cell, they display respectively "1.00.00", "1.10.00", "1.20.00", "1.30.00".

Why this behavior? Is it normal or is it a bug? Are they interpreted like sexagesimal?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pmUOyRoSQXvAldG_9ixUOu2YBTsmTreUMmoKZQpE8sI/edit?usp=sharing

**Recorded Clip:**
https://photos.app.goo.gl/vV7FhrvrguDsAMwDA

EDIT: I've obtained the same behavior on Google Chrome (Windows), Microsoft Edge (Windows) and Google Spreadsheets (Android).

Thank you

Comment: Interesting problem. There's no bug that I'm aware of. Would you share the spreadsheet so we can see the context? Would you also check whether the "," separated values are being expressed as numbers or text. The function =ISNUMBER will tell you.

Comment: Yes, it returns TRUE. I also edited the original post, check it please! Ty

Comment: Is there a script file attached to this sheet?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: The behaviour is extremely odd, particularly if there is no script acting on the data. 
Can we please see the spreadsheet?

Comment: I've done it, check the original post. Tell me if you can see it, please. Try to find and replace. TY

Comment: can you share an editable version of the sheet? we need to inspect data + cell settings

Comment: I've done it, check the original post.

Comment: The spreadsheet seems OK. I could NOT replicate any of the issues that you mention in your question. The locale is set to Italy (decimal separator = "comma") but if you can change locale to, say, Australia (decimal separator = "period") then all the entries simply change from comma to decimal point. "Find and Replace" (via "Edit") doesn't work (because the entries are numbers); same with the REPLACE function.  None returned the inconsistent results you experienced. TimeZone is Berlin, but that doesn't seem relevant.

Comment: Thank you for your support. I'll record a clip to show this behavior.

Comment: I've recorded the clip, check the OP

Answer (score 0):

The automatic formatting is choosing to display as time, ie `75` as 1 hour 15 minutes, or `1.15` (with seconds of `00` when the cell is clicked). It won't behave this way if formatted as Plain text before replacement of `,` by `.`.

Comment: Sorry but that's not an answer, we've already understood that behavior but the question is: why? And why is it so unpredictable?